# Did Jesus come to restore the immortality that Adam and Eve lost?

Tags: life-of-jesus, adam, immortality

So The Bible in The Book of Genesis describes that Adam and Eve were created as
*immortal*,But this *immortal* is not equal to the Godly *immortal* as its tied to a law, if Adam and Eve break the law of God then they lose all rights to  access this *immortality*. Proof that Adam and Eve were immortal prior to the fall.

**Genesis 2:17**

> but you must not eat from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, for when you eat from it you will certainly die

The verse above means that as long as Adam and Eve avoided the tree of knowledge of good and evil, the were never going to die.

It can also be noted that this *immortality* needs the *Tree of Life* for perpetuation. God seals access to the *Tree of Life* to prevent Adam and Eve from eating of it to leave forever as sinners. Check out the verse below for more details.

**Genesis 3:22**

> And the LORD God said, “The man has now become like one of us, knowing good and evil. He must not be allowed to reach out his hand and take also from the tree of life and eat, and live forever.

In order to protect the tree above then a flaming sword that turns in all directions was placed at the East of the garden after Adam and Eve are sent out. It could also be that the devil was jealous of Adam's and Eve immortality and lied to them so that they would lose it.

But also this was part of the plan as Abraham sacrificing Isaac was a foreshadowing of God sacrificing the Christ for the sins of the whole world.

So did Jesus come to restore the immortality that Adam and Eve lost?
Is this immortality the same as that the enjoyed in the garden? Will Jesus allow the saints to eat from the tree of life?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bible nowhere states that Adam and Eve were created immortal, or that they had immortality granted to them before they sinned. This is often assumed, but there is nothing in Genesis (or elsewhere) that says such a thing.

If they already had immortality, why would God have told them that there was the Tree of Life in the center of the garden? Clearly, they had not partaken of its fruit (life eternal) because they chose to partake of the fruit of the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil, which resulted in death. They then had to be put out of the garden, with cherubs preventing them getting to the Tree of Life.

Genesis is clear. They could have had eternal life, but they chose to partake of that which God had warned them would result in death. That sinful choice then debarred them from life eternal. It is not until the last book of the Bible that the Tree of Life makes another appearance, in heaven.

Because Jesus is the LAST Adam, and the SECOND man, this denotes a new humanity, in Christ, that is not of the seed of the first Adam. Those who are granted eternal life in the paradise of God partake spiritually of Christ, by faith.

Sometimes it's a good idea to leave a few days open for other contributions, as other points may become clear in other answers.

Comment: but you do know they were never going to die as long as they never touched the tree? a state of not dying qualifies to be immortal by itself.

Comment: what is the difference between eternal life and immortality?

Comment: @Dong Li  it was Eve's error that God had said not to touch the tree. God said no such thing. It was partaking of the fruit that was the issue. Immortality belongs to God (1 Timothy 6:16) - life with no beginning and no end. He grants life eternal to those whom he will but they cannot 'earn' that. It is a gift of grace and faith is key. You would need to ask a fresh question to get full answers to that. You ask about deeply complex spiritual matters and sound-bite answers just will not do!

Comment: what could have happened if they also reached out and ate of the tree of life? I get a feeling that God locked the tree up because if they were allowed to eat of the tree of life after sinning then that could not be undone because God says "The would have lived forever as sinners" which is a state currently held by fallen angels.

Comment: @Dong Li I argue that the story makes more sense if they were eating of the tree of life as long as they were in the garden. This gave them life as long as they continued.  The expulsion interrupted something they had been doing already.

Comment: @Dong Li  It’s not a case of “What if…” The Bible tells us what happened. We are not to speculate, for then we either add to God’s word, or take away from it. No sinner can live forever because the Bible tells us that “the wages of sin is death, but the gift of God is eternal life through Jesus Christ our Lord.” (Romans 6:23) Sort that out, and Genesis will become clearer.

Comment: @StephenDisraeli There is a lot of mystery surrounding the garden, what was their state inside the garden, were they spirits or were the in the flesh? the tree of life is in the paradise of God which was their home before they were sent out and this garden existed during the time of Adam, does exist now and will be unlocked for the saints who overcome. Could this imply that Adam and Eve were spirits in the garden then assumed the flesh when they were sent out? but then he formed them out of the same dust that is in the garden, this is very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

"To him who conquers, I will grant to eat of the tree of life which is in the paradise of God" (Revelation ch2 v7, RSV).

I believe that answers your last question. The tree is found as available in Revelation ch22 v2.

On the restoration of what was lost in Adam, we have (for example) "The last Adam became a lifegiving spirit" and "Just as we have borne the image of the man of dust, we shall also bear the image of the man of heaven" (1 Corinthians ch15 v45 and v49).

The point is further explained in Romans ch5; "If, because of one man's trespass, death reigned through that one man [Adam]. much more will those who receive the abundance of grace... reign in life through the one man Jesus Christ" (v17). "So that, as sin reigned in death, grace also might reign through righteousness *to eternal life* through |Jesus Christ our Lord" (v21).

Comment: is the last Adam Jesus Christ?

Comment: Yes, that is what Paul means. His readers will have known that, but he spells it out in v57 of that chapter; "Thanks be to God, who gives us the victory through our Lord Jesus Christ".

Comment: Amen, it is good that God promises a reward for all those who overcome the world.